# Regular expression starting at least with 2

Tags: regex

I am trying to get/make a regular expression but i can't figure it out. I am searching for an expression so that a user, who is filling a form, can't type 0 ore 1. So it has to start at least with 2. What is the expression for it?

Thanks a lot.

---

Thanks. But this is not 100% waterproof. As a user you can't fill 0 or 1 but you can't fill 10 or 11 or 101 either. So everything with a 0 or a 1 at the beginning. Is there a solution?

Thanks again.

Comment: share some sample inputs along with expected output and what have you tried till now.

Comment: Is 0 or 1 allowed after 2. Is only digits are allowed?

Answer (score 1):

here, this should accept any numbers starting with 2 or more:

```
[2-9][0-9]*
```

or

```
^[2-9][0-9]*$
```

if you are matching whole lines.

Comment: add `^` in the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

I understand you mean it begins with a digit from 2 to 9, but you should tell if it can contain else later.

for pure numbers:

```
[2-9][0-9]*
```

this forces the content be numeric ans start with a digit > 1.
Use:

```
[2-9][0-9]+
```

if more than one number is mandatory,

This works as exact match, if you are doing a non-exact match use anchoring:

```
^[2-9][0-9]*$
```

if after the initial digit different character can happen use an appropriate pattern e.g:

```
[2-9].*
```

matches anything after the first digit:

[2-9][0-9a-zA-Z]*

matches a alfanumeric pattern etc...

Answer (score 0):

If you mean to accept any string that is an integer number bigger than 1:

```
([1][0-9]+|[2-9][0-9]*)
```

the first half ([1][0-9]+) will match a number starting by 1 followed by at least another digit, the second will match the numbers 2-9 or a number starting with a digit 2-9 and more figures ([2-9][0-9]*).

Note that this does not accept potentially good integers written with a leading 0, like 0123. If you want to include that as well use:

```
(0*[1][0-9]+|0*[2-9][0-9]*)
```

Also note that a pattern like:

```
(matcher1|matcher2)
```

is not supported by all RE engines.

Answer (score -2):

I reckon something like this would be useful for you:

**(2+)(.)***

It's mean that only words starting with "2" math the expression.
If you wanna try regular expressiona easely, i like the web http://rubular.com/
It has a good interface to test expressions directly onto the web.

Greetings

Comment: Ok, I do not understan you.
In that case you need something like:
**^[2-9]+(.)***
This solution must hav a start with a number between 2 and 9, follow by anything else numbers, letters or anything.

Greetings